# Como faço para manipular os dados de um select criado a partir de jquery

Tags: jquery, select, value

Estou tentando pegar os valores de um select que eu inseri através de um jquery, e conforme o valor ele adicione elementos dentro de uma div também criada por esse mesmo jquery. O problema é que eu não estou conseguindo pegar esses valor.

Esse é o código onde eu insiro o select dentro de uma div criada no html.

```
<!-- Jquery Add Formulario -->
<script>

$(function AddForm() {
    var adicionar = $('.grid');
        $(document).on('click', '#id_AddMais', function () {
            $('<div  class="questionario w3-col m11 w3-white w3-padding-large">'+
              '<form method="POST" action="">'+

                  '<div class="w3-half">'+
                    '<input id="id_Enunciado" class="w3-input" type="text" name="txtEnunciado" placeholder="Enunciado">'+
                  '</div>'+

                  '<div class="styled-select w3-light-grey w3-right slate">'+

                  '<select id="id_FormaResposta" name="formaResposta">'+

                  '<optgroup>'+
                    '<option value="respostaCurta">Resposta curta</option>'+
                    '<option value="paragrafo">Parágrafo</option>'+
                  '</optgroup>'+

                  '<optgroup>'+
                    '<option value="multiplaEscolha">Múltipla escolha</option>'+
                    '<option value="caixasDeSelecao">Caixas de seleção</option>'+
                    '<option value="listaSuspensa">Lista suspensa</option>'+
                  '</optgroup>'+

                  '<optgroup>'+
                    '<option value="uploadArquivo">Upload de arquivo</option>'+
                  '</optgroup>'+

                  '<optgroup>'+
                    '<option value="escalaLinear">Escala linear</option>'+
                    '<option value="gradeME">Grade de múltipla escolha</option>'+
                  '</optgroup>'+

                  '<optgroup>'+
                    '<option value="data">Data</option>'+
                    '<option value="horario">Horário</option>'+
                  '</optgroup>'+

                  '</select>'+
                '</div>'+

                '<input id="id_Suporte" class="w3-input" type="text" name="txtSuporte" placeholder="Suporte">'+

                '<input id="id_Comando" class="w3-input" type="text" name="txtComando" placeholder="Comando">'+

              '</form><br>'+

              '<div class="divResposta">'+

              '</div><br>'+

              '<button  onclick="" id="id_Excluir" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-right" style="color: grey"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></button>'+
              '<button  onclick="" id="id_Copiar" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-right" style="color: grey"><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button>'+


            '</div>').appendTo(adicionar);
            return false;
       });

       $(document).on('click', '#id_Excluir', function () {
             $(this).parents('.questionario').remove();
               return false;
       });
});
</script>
```

Aqui estou "pegando" o valor do select e tentando inserir elementos dentro da div(divResposta) criada anteriormente.

```
<!-- Pegar valor select -->
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#id_FormaResposta').on('change', function(){

    var valorSelect = $(this).val();
    var modificarDiv = $('.divResposta');

    if(valorSelect == 'paragrafo'){

        $(
            '<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Paragrafo" disabled >'

        ).appendTo(modificarDiv);
        return false;

    }

});

});

</script>
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Tens a certeza que só há um id `'#id_FormaResposta'` na página toda? Testa delegar assim: `$(document).on('change', '#id_FormaResposta', function(){`

Comment: Chega a entrar no change do select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei a sequencia das adições do HTML na sua página, mas, supondo que você definiu os eventos e depois chamou: AddForm, que adicionou os elementos, o evento do change não vai ser disparado, pq foi delegado antes de o elemento ter sido renderizado. Então vamos trocar a atribuição para o document.

Sugiro que, já que você adiciona varios formulários, não utilize o id para o select, que definiria um elemento único, mas uma classe. E seu código ficaria como:

```
$(document).on('change', '.FormaResposta', function(){
    var valorSelect = $(this).val();
    var modificarDiv = $(this).parents(".questionario").find('.divResposta');

    if(valorSelect == 'paragrafo'){
        $('<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Paragrafo" disabled >').appendTo(modificarDiv);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Obrigado dessa forma deu certo.

Comment: Porém como a primeira jquery possibilita criar vários  selects eles tem sempre os mesmos valores, então esta adicionando  esse input no caso nas duas selects criadas.. como faço para arrumar isso? (não sei se deu pra entender bem)

Comment: Você não deveria ter mais de um elemento com o mesmo ID, é por isso que está acontecendo isso. Para cada vez que ele clica em: addMais, tu precisa replicar todo aquele HTML mesm, @wolf?

Comment: eu não sei  se tem alguma outra forma de fazer, mas é que como sera possível preencher quantos formulários for desejado com as mesmas informações, essa foi a maneira que eu achei...

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, @wolf.

Comment: Nossa muito obrigado mesmo, agora esta funcionando certinho..

Comment: @wolf, se a resposta te ajudou e tu não tem mais dúvidas, pode marcar como aceita para que outras pessoas possam ser ajudadas também.